# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, lame

I want to use LAME project in my application,

I have found one example project which uses LAME project in it, now the lame project is working fine in example project.

I want to use same LAME project in my project for that I have copied all required files and folders in my projects respective directory Ex: armeiabi from libs of example project goes to my projects libs folder, I have replaced com.example.Lame with com.myproject.Lame in all the files but still I am getting java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: error.

What I have to do to use native LAME project in my android project. I know I have to use NDK to generate .so file but can copying it from another project work for me?

Answer (score 0):

When calling native methods the package name is in the Java part and in the native part. Changing it on one side results in the error you encounter.

You have to change the name in the c/c++ part, too and recompile it.